# How to include nodes/ways that match no tag in osm2pgql

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis, osm2pgsql

Is it possible to include the entire dataset into PostGIS? Currently only the nodes/ways having matching tag are imported. Can we make any changes to the style file to make that happen?

Edit:

osm2pgsql -c -d Map -U postgres -H localhost -S C:\osm2pgsql\default.style C:\Users\Saloni\Desktop\map.osm

Map is my database in Postgres

Comment: Are you using `osm2pgsql`? Please add your actual code to the question

Comment: @TommasoDiBucchianico I have added the command I am using to import data to pgAdminIII. I need to have all the nodes and ways in the DB(untagged or tagged).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the `--hstore` option? With this option osm2pgql will store all key-value-pairs in a hash container, see the postgresql documentation for the [hstore data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html). Although I'm mot sure if this even imports elements that don't have any matching tag in the style file.

Comment: I had to edit my OSM data file to import all the nodes. I had to add tags to all the nodes. But thanks anyway :)